# How to print a variable?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

When I use a while loop then my result coming like this.

```
$skin_type_id = '';
while ($res = $query->fetchObject()) {
    if (isset($res->skin_type_id) && $res->skin_type_id != '') {
        $skin_type_id .= $res->skin_type_id;
    }
}
```

**Output:**
471112131415174019

I want output like this:

47

11

12

13

14

15

17

40

19

so how can I do this?

Comment: maybe `$skin_type_id .= $res->skin_type_id."<br/>";` ?

Comment: Make `$skin_type_id` an array, like `$skin_type_id = []` and in your loop `$skin_type_id[] = $res->skin_type_id` which you can then loop in a `foreach ($skin_type_id as $id)` and `echo $id . '<br>'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<br>` when you print your value.Something like this:

```
$skin_type_id .= $res->skin_type_id."<br>";
```

Comment: any other options ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values to unique array keys and then loop foreach of the indices and echo them out with a `<br>` tag after it, this allows you to manipulate your `$skin_type_id` values before outputting them.

```
$skin_type_id = [];
while ($res = $query->fetchObject()) {
    if (isset($res->skin_type_id) && $res->skin_type_id != '') {
        $skin_type_id[] = $res->skin_type_id;
    }
}
// do something with your $skin_type_id array which contains integers
foreach ($skin_type_id as $id)
{
    echo $id . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Why should he do 2 loops instead of one? You did almost same, but here you need two loops

Comment: @Danielius because of assigning the values along with a `<br>` tag in a string, assigning the id's to a array before outputting them allows one to work with the data if necessary, such as formatting easier formatting html along with the data. This might however be unnecessary for OP's usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($res = $query->fetchObject()) {
    if (isset($res->skin_type_id) && $res->skin_type_id != '') {
        echo $res->skin_type_id."<br>";
    }
}
```

Even this should work. you wont need an array declared for this.